# Fetching data by composite primary key in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, composite-primary-key

I am using following function ->

```
const params = {
        TableName: process.env.dummyTable,
        Key: {

               outlet_id:event.pathParametrs.id,
               id:{"S":"default"} 


        }

    }
dynamoDb.get(params).promise()
        .then(result => {
          console.log('-->',result);
          const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(result),
          };

          callback(null, response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          callback(new Error('Couldn\'t fetch table Data'));
          return;
        });
     }
```

I want to fetch records based on outlet_id and id.Here outlet_id is primary partition key while id is primary sort key(with uuid).
  How to specify id(primary sort key) with default value so that I can fetch data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear whether you are trying to fetch a single item by specifying a composite partition+sort key, or trying to query all items with the same partition key (ie. without specifying a sort key).

If you were trying to get a single item, with a particular partition key and sort key, your code looks good with one exception. The partition key should be specified with the type as well, like so:

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.dummyTable,
    Key: {
           outlet_id:{"S": event.pathParametrs.id},
           id:{"S":"default"} 
    }
}
```

However, if you are trying to query for all items with the same partition key (ie. without specifying a sort key) then you would need to modify the code to do a [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) rather than a get:

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.dummyTable,
    Key: {
           outlet_id: {"S": event.pathParametrs.id}
    }
}
dynamoDb.query(params).promise()
.then(
  //...
)
.catch(
  //...
)
```

Comment: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params. Hehehehe